# Best way to filter Mongoid documents based on attributes quickly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am a relative newbie to Rails and Mongoid so apologies if the answer to this question should be obvious. :)

I'm building a Rails 3 app that will allow users to find Movies based on the attributes for the movies. I have a `MoviesController` with an `index` action that allows the user to sort based on attributes in the `Movie` model (like `genre`, `studio`, etc.).

I've come up with the following solution, but this doesn't feel sustainable as it's already started to slow down as my db has grown.

```
# controllers/movies_controller.rb

def index
  if params[:genre]
    @movies = Movie.where(:genre => params[:genre])
  elsif params[:studio]
    @movies = Movie.where(:studio => params[:studio])
  else
    @movies = Movie.all
  end
end

# views/movies/index.html.erb

<li><%= link_to "Action", movies_path(:genre => "Action") %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Suspense", movies_path(:genre => "Suspense") %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Drama", movies_path(:genre => "Drama") %></li>
...

<li><%= link_to "Paramount", movies_path(:studio => "Paramount") %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Universal", movies_path(:studio => "Universal") %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Disney", movies_path(:studio => "Disney") %></li>
...
```

I've explored action and fragment caching to speed things up, but I have to think there's a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make indexes on genere and studio.

In the mongo shell:

```
db.movies.ensureIndex({genre: 1})
db.movies.ensureIndex({studio: 1})
```

If you want to do this inside mongoid there is some information on that [here](http://mongoid.org/docs/indexing.html).

Basically, within the class:

```
class Movie
    index :genre
    index :studio
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One line response: adding an index to your collections might speed things up.

Long response: You're thinking of adding caching to an application because the DB feels slow, and you probably know that if you were using a relational engine then that stuff would be fine. You should be developing your app, not worrying about how to cache stuff :)

Is there anything in your application preventing you from using a traditional relational engine? If there is, go ahead, use indices and maybe that will fix it. If not, why go for Mongo?

Comment: Thanks Federico, I'll take a look at my indexing strategies to see if that speeds things up. I originally opted for MongoDB so I wouldn't have to worry about migrations and because I'm also modeling TV Shows in my app and I found it to be more efficient to embed "Episode" objects within my "Show" documents.